# logging ng-click centrally

Tags: logging, click, angularjs

On my angular-js application I would like track how each user uses it. Thus initially I am building a log mechanism on the client in order to track what the user clicks and then send the data onto my server.

The main question here is that I would like to log all ng-click events across my application. Is it possible to do this centralized and not have to go to each functions and add my functionality?

Ultimately I would like to include in the log message the id of the div that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Use a directive and a service, like this:

```
app.directive('logClickEvent', function(Logger) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
      element.bind('click', function(event) {
        Logger.logEvent(event);
      });
    }
  }  
})

app.factory('Logger', function () {
  return { 
    logEvent: function(event) {
      // implement your logger logic here
    }
  };
});
```

And then place the directive on all the elements you want to log:

```
<button id="button1" log-click-event>button1</button>
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/7wBsv/

**option #2**: 'Override' `ng-click`: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/7wBsv/2/

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to avoid doing, that is revisiting all the clickable divs and adding log-click-event. What I am hoping is  adding functionality (or extending) the ng-click. ie. for say ng-click=clickfunction(); the "logger logic" would also be executed. Is this something feasible?

Comment: I don't know if that's a good idea... but here it goes: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/7wBsv/2/

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a click-event handler to the html body/document object and handling it that way?

Expanding on bmleite's jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/w8txe/3/

The main thing is though, if logging the ID will be informative enough, and if not - how are you going to pull out the relevant information to make the logging useful?

Could always pass in $location / $rootScope / etc to pull out some more contextual information in the log handler.

```
<body log-click-event>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <button id="button1">button1</button>
      <button id="button2">button2</button>
     <div id="div1" class="box">
          <ul>
              <li id="li1">Some LI</li>
              <li id="li2">Some LI</li>
              <li id="li3">Some LI</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
<div>
```